# Custom Django Rest Framework authentication validating when 'None' is returned

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am working on implementing JWT for authentication. Of course, this means I have to do some custom authentication. According to the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication), "If authentication is not attempted, return `None`." So, I have code that checks for an authorization header (where the JWT resides) and returning "None" if an authorization header does not exist. This means that authorization was not attempted (and according to the docs) I should return `None`. However, Django is saying that the user is authorized:

Root/authentication/TokenAuthentication/TokenAuthentication

```
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.authentication import get_authorization_header, BaseAuthentication
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import jwt, json

class TokenAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()

        if not auth:
            return None
```

Login.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login_view(request):
    if not request.data:
        return Response({'Error': "Please provide username/password"}, status="400")

    username = request.data['username']
    password = request.data['password']

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)

        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise User.DoesNotExist

    except User.DoesNotExist: # if user not found or password is wrong
        return Response({'Error': "Invalid username/password"}, status="400")

    if user.is_authenticated:
        print("user is authenticated") # THIS GETS PRINTED
    else:
        print("User is not authenticated")
```

Settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        #'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'Root.authentication.TokenAuthentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
}
```

The line

```
 if user.is_authenticated:
        print("user is authenticated")
```

Is running everytime when `None` is being returned.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Note: If it matters, I'm using PyJwt.

Comment: Did you add any headers to your request?

Comment: No I did not. I did that on purpose. By not adding any headers, that code gets run and returns None, but the user is still authenticated. I don't think the user should be though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are Using **`user.is_authenticated`** to check the authentication, where **`user`** is the instance ***you pulled from the Database***.
It should be **`request.user.is_authenticated`**